# Repeated regex replace within bounds

Tags: regex, fsm, pushdown-automaton

I have a number of references I would like to have replaced with links to the anchors further down in the text. The links have a very regular form, so it should be quite doable - at least with a script:

A reference "[44]" should be replaced with the following html code: `[<a href="ref44">44</a>]`.

That one is easy enough. Simple replacement with a backreference. But is there a regex (vim dialect, python, or ... perl, if must be. The horror!) that can convert the following into similar links: `[44,45,77,91]`?
That is, one link per number, where the group of links are surrounded by a pair of square brackets.

Since this involves (theoritcally unbounded) memory, it does not map 1:1 with a FSM, and as such should rather be handled by some kind of pushdown-automaton, not a regex, but some dialects are a lot more powerful, so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-run this regex replace until no more replacements are made.

Regex: `(\[(?:<a(?=\s|>)(?:[^>=|&)]|='(?:[^']|\\')*'|="(?:[^"]|\\")*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>.*?<\/a>,)*)(\d+)([,\]])`

Replace with: `$1<a href="ref$2">$2</a>$3`

[image]

The portion which captures group 1, will match event the most sophisticated complex anchor tags.

## Examples

**Sample Text**

```
[22][44,45,77,91]
```

**After Replacement**

<sub>First time:</sub>

```
[<a href="ref22">22</a>][<a href="ref44">44</a>,45,77,91]
```

<sub>Second time:</sub>

```
[<a href="ref22">22</a>][<a href="ref44">44</a>,<a href="ref45">45</a>,77,91]
```

<sub>Third time:</sub>

```
[<a href="ref22">22</a>][<a href="ref44">44</a>,<a href="ref45">45</a>,<a href="ref77">77</a>,91]
```

<sub>Fourth time:</sub>

```
[<a href="ref22">22</a>][<a href="ref44">44</a>,<a href="ref45">45</a>,<a href="ref77">77</a>,<a href="ref91">91</a>]
```

Comment: Nice work! But you are saying that it is not possible in the same regex, right? I would basically loop a string through that regex, checking for the condition that the string has been unchanged. If so, then you kind of answered that it is not possible and came up with a pragmatic solution, which is fine :)

Comment: Without knowing the language this will be used with, that's exactly what I'm saying. The problem with doing this with a single expression is dealing with the potentially infinite number of values enclosed in brackets and the limitations some languages have with their implementation of regular expressions.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was expecting given that the text book definition of a regex equals an FSM (which can't deal with unlimited memory/states).

Comment: You could do it with the .net implementation of regex: `(?<=\[(?:(?:\d+|<a(?=\s|>)(?:[^>=|&)]|='(?:[^']|\\')*'|="(?:[^"]|\\")*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>.*?<\/a>),)*)(\d+)(?=(,\d+)*\])` and replace with:  `<a href="ref$1">$1</a>`, but this uses a lookbehind with infinite series which is illegal in several popular languages.